# Should this be genitive?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

In the following passage, shouldn't кораблекрушение be in the genitive case? Or is this a typo?

“Из разговора также совершенно ясно, что вахтенный заметил в свете хвостовых прожекторов человека, потерпевшего **кораблекрушение**.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct in that sentence, the Accusative case is used correctly. `Потерпеть` is a transitive word, and its direct object, `кораблекрушение` is naturally in the Accusative case.

Comment: I was looking at потерпевшего as a noun meaning "victim," but now I see it's actually a participle.

Comment: @CocoPop - Yes it's a participle, the comma before it clearly indicates it's a participle. Still, that participle can be substantivized, used as a noun, but even in such case "кораблекрушение" will still be in Accusative.

Comment: Really? So to state "the victim of a shipwreck" it would remain потерпевший кораблекрушение?

Comment: @CocoPop - Yes, exactly. Substantivized participles keep the government of the verb they are formed from. There's another word for "the victim", "жертва", and it's a real noun, with it "кораблекрушение" will really be in the Genitive case: "жертва кораблекрушения."

Comment: Got it! I didn't know that binding principle of substantivized participles. That is very helpful. Thank you  :)

Comment: @YellowSky How can you use _потерпевший_ as a noun with _кораблекрушение_ in the accusative?

Comment: @jwalker - In a lots of ways, like this, for example: "Моряки заметили лодку с потерпевшими кораблекрушение." - "The sailors noticed a boat with the victims of a shipwreck." Or like this: "Потерпевший кораблекрушение провёл неделю на необитаемом острове." - "A victim of the shipwreck spent a week on an uninhabited island."

Comment: Great examples! I'm glad my mind wanted a genitive - it shows that I'm developing a feeling for the cases. The fact that I also understand your "lesson" adds another dimension to my навыки. Thank you

Comment: @YellowSky To me the whole phrase _потерпевший кораблекрушение_ is substantivized, and _потерпевший_ itself keeps its participle properties. This way you don't have a "weird" noun dependent on another noun in a typical transitive verb paradigm.